# Compute standardized mean difference and its standard error from regression-adjusted mean and 95% CI for 2 groups

Tags: meta-analysis, cohens-d

I am working on a meta-analysis (using aggregated data), where the outcome is a continuous variable. One study reported post-treatment outcome values as regression-adjusted mean and 95% CI in each of the groups under comparison: treatment and control.

I am interested to compute the standardized mean difference (SMD) and its standard error (SE). If I transform the reported 95% CI to standard deviation (SD) and I obtain the adjusted mean and adjusted SD for each group, is it appropriate to use the same formulae (please see below) to compute SMD and its SE as for the unadjusted/raw means?

Are there any other ways/formulae to compute SMD and its SE that take into account the fact that the summary data reported by the study is adjusted?

Thanks in advance!

Formulae to compute SMD and SE using unadjusted mean and SD:

$SMD = \frac{\mu_1 - \mu_2}{\sigma_{pooled}}$

$\sigma_{pooled} = \sqrt{\frac{(n_1-1)\sigma_1^2+(n_2-1)\sigma_2^2}{n_1+n_2-2}}$

$SE_{SMD} = \sqrt{\frac{n_1+n_2}{n_1n_2} + \frac{SMD^2}{2(n_1+n_2-2)}}$